# Magento 2: Installing patch with Composer - package "not locked"

Tags: extensions, magento2.4, patches, composer

An established Magento extension company sent me a patch to install as there was an issue with our local installation. I tried installing it with Composer but it didn’t seem to change the code in the relevant files. When I look at it I still see the same code on the lines referred to by the patch.

I installed the patch using Composer following these instructions: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/patching/composer.html. I required the cweagans via command line and then added the following to composer.json

```
"extra": {
"magento-force": "override",
"composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
"patches": {
"company/modulename": {
"SUPPORT-10090": "SUPPORT-10090.patch"
}
}
}
```

In the command line I used this: php composer.phar update company/modulename and got

```
Gathering patches for root package.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Package "company/modulename " listed for update is not locked.
```

Is the package not being "locked" causing an issue and how would I fix it? I have already contacted them again but thought it might be something I could fix more quickly than waiting for them to get back to me. Also the patch seems to be just a couple of lines, would it be very bad of me to just copy the couple of lines into the code directly, at least temporarily - is that going to cause any issues? Thanks

Comment: Did you try this command? - composer require company/modulename

Comment: No - thanks! but I just did and got errors relating to requirements and dependencies which pertain to the initial installation where there was an issue with conflicts with another extension. So that might be what is happening. It looks like I might need to wait for them to get back to me. Thanks anyway